# Referencing JS and CSS in sandbox web parts error

Tags: sandbox-solution

I am trying to reference JS and CSS files in sandbox web part, but once I try to deploy it gives me this error:

> The expression prefix 'SPUrl' was not recognized.  Please correct the
>   prefix or register the prefix in the  section of
>   configuration.

I am referencing my css and js this way:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/assets/js/modernizr.js %>" ID="modernizr" runat="server" ></SharePoint:ScriptLink>
<SharePoint:CssRegistration ID="CssRegistration1" Name="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/assets/css/style.css %>" runat="server" After="corev15.css" ></SharePoint:CssRegistration>
```

Anything wrong with that? Is there a limitation for this in Sandbox solutions?

Comment: Did you try removing SPUrl and simply start with tilde and site collection token. Also remove starting and ending less than , grester than and percent symbols

Comment: Hi Nadeem, can you show me a snippet of what you mean?

Comment: `Name="~sitecollection/style library/assets/js/modernizr.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it turns out that both `ScriptLink` and `CssRegistration` are not available in Sandboxed solutions. These are in `Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls` namespace and you don’t have access to that in Sandboxed solutions. The fix is to use `<link>` tag for CSS. Example:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/assets/css/style.css %>" />
```

Similarly use following code to refer to JavaScript file:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<% $SPUrl:~sitecollection/style library/assets/js/modernizr.js %>"></script>
```

Sources: http://blog.pixelmill.com/1143/cssregistration-sharepoint-2010-sandbox/
http://blog.pixelmill.com/1150/link-javascript-files-sharepoint-2010-sandbox-solution/
https://coder87.wordpress.com/2013/09/30/cssregistration-is-not-allowed-in-sharepoint-2013-sandbox/

Comment: Hi Nadeem. It's now telling me: `Literal expressions like '<% $SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/assets/css/style.css %>' are not allowed. Use <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="<%$SPUrl:~SiteCollection/Style%20Library/assets/css/style.css%>" /> instead.
`
I can't even deploy the web part, it's telling me `Error 1 The name 'InitializeControl' does not exist in the current context` unless I remove the references.

Comment: Hmm, in that case can you try to write the code in the .cs file of the webpart as described in PixelMill blog. The first two source links I have provided. What it is doing is that it is getting the Url of the root site collection and appending it ot the file location in style library.

Comment: Is this the recommended way of doing it in Sandbox? I just want to learn the right thing, so if you say so I will go with it.

Comment: As can be seen neither `ScriptLink` nor `ScriptLink` is allowed in sandboxed solutions. Secondly, it appears from your error that `$SPUrl:~SiteCollection` tokens are also not working. So, finally option left is to use full url of the css and js file. One way which I wont like personally is to hardcode the url, something like "http://yourootsite/stylelibrary/yourcss.css" and same for .js file. However, a better approach is to dynamically generate the root site collection url in the code and then inject other parts. Choice is yours.