# How to create a search using sharepoint JSOM

Tags: client-object-model

I'm new to SharePoint and JSOM and i'm trying to build up a search using JSOM.

and i tried below code snippets

I FOLLOWED FOLLOWING BLOG
http://www.dotnetmafia.com/blogs/dotnettipoftheday/archive/2013/04/18/how-to-query-search-with-the-sharepoint-2013-javascript-client-object-model.aspx

Is there any `search.js` file i should linked? if so what would be the link??
However these are the links i added

1st step: Create a page and added following HTML

It has search button : `#searchButton` and text box : `#searchTextBox`

i linked JQuery and `abc.js` file succesfully

and added this JS code to abc.js file

```
'use strict';

var results;

var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();


$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#searchButton").click(function () {

       alert('check1');
        var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(context);
        keywordQuery.set_queryText($("#searchTextBox").val());

       alert('check2');

        var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(context);
        results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);

        context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySuccess, onQueryFail)
    });
});


function onQuerySuccess() {
    $("#resultsDiv").append('<table>');

    $.each(results.m_value.ResultTables[0].ResultRows, function () {
        $("#resultsDiv").append('<tr>');
        $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Title + '</td>');
        $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Author + '</td>');
        $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Write + '</td>');
        $("#resultsDiv").append('<td>' + this.Path + '</td>');
        $("#resultsDiv").append('</tr>');
    });

    $("#resultsDiv").append('</table>');
}

function onQueryFail(sender, args) {
    alert('Query failed. Error:' + args.get_message());
}
```

In this code check1 alert is coming but not the check2 alert.. Whats the wrong with this..?

Comment: Have you added reference to `SP.Search.js`

Answer (score 8):

For quite some time, I used to get around a similar issue in regards to the Search API. Over and over again I was troubled with the following error-message:

> Object doesn't support this action

Try to add a reference/key to `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery` instead of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query`.

At least that worked for me.

Working sample below:

```
function Search() {
    var d = $.Deferred();

    SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.js", "SP.ClientContext", function () {
        SP.SOD.executeFunc("SP.Search.js", "Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery", function () {
            var sContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
            var keywordQuery = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.KeywordQuery(sContext);
            keywordQuery.set_trimDuplicates(false);
            keywordQuery.set_queryText("*");
            var searchExecutor = new Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query.SearchExecutor(sContext);
            results = searchExecutor.executeQuery(keywordQuery);
            sContext.executeQueryAsync(
                function () {
                    d.resolve(results);
                },
                function (err) {
                    d.reject(null);
                }
            );
        });
    });

    return d.promise();
}
```

Comment: The code snippet working like a charm, thanks, very helpful

Answer (score 2):

You are most probably missing the reference to `SP.Search.js` file. Add following code to add reference to it:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="SP.Search.js" OnDemand="true" runat="server" Localizable="false">
</SharePoint:ScriptLink>
```

Then in the `$(document).ready(` method call it using `SP.SOD.executeFunc` function.
Example:
`SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Search.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query', SetSearchSettings);` 
- See more at: http://onlinecoder.blogspot.in/2014/03/loading-javascript-libraries-only-when.html#sthash.k2B2SvJd.dpuf

**UPDATE**

Based on the comments, it also looks like sp.js file is also not loaded. Add these script references also:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="MicrosoftAjax.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.core.js" runat="server" Defer="False" Localizable="false"/>
<SharePoint:ScriptLink Name="SP.js" runat="server" Defer="True" Localizable="false"/>
```

Comment: Hi, Thank you very much for repling me, I ADDED following code and as well as i added sp.search.js too..
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.Search.js', 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Search.Query', SetSearchSettings);

looks like it has some issue, after that code does not getting executed.  

Any idea, really appreciate ur help

Comment: it looks code does not work after this tooo.. any libraries to be loaded to run following two code lines?
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

Comment: Keep the code in abc.js as you had earlier and only add `<SharePoint:ScriptLink language="javascript" name="SP.Search.js" runat="server">
</SharePoint:ScriptLink>` to the .aspx page

Comment: i just followed your instruction, and
i put two alerts between those two statesments 
alert('above');
 
var results;
 
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var user = context.get_web().get_currentUser();

alert('below');

above alert is coming up but not the below..

Comment: can you paste the whole code of your .aspx page in the question?

Comment: i've uploaded APEX page there.. Thanks a lot for interest

Comment: https://www.zeta-uploader.com/606022001 , because apex page is too large, can't paste everything

Comment: That looks good. Try opening the browser developer tools check what error is thrown.

Comment: somewhere it says  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined''
haven't i loaded any library?

Comment: @SharePointLearner, see my updated answer.

Comment: Is it ok to always put Name="SP.js" isn't there any correct path?? because i'm using sandbox enviroment and my page url is something like
https://xxxx.com/sites/sandbox/crtest/SitePages/TestPage%20JS%20Model.aspx

Comment: Oh, is this a sandbox project? You should have mentioned that in the question. See this question: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130362/referencing-js-and-css-in-sandbox-web-parts-error/130372?noredirect=1#comment132442_130372

Comment: But when i go to pagesource it has sp.js file  and all other files, (once i clicked on it will be redirected to a js file)..
But still it says Cannot read property 'get_current' of undefined..

I'm really really not sure whats going on .. i 1000 times appreicate your help

Comment: Finally i was able to get a result from this code. But it only gives one result, which is the app created by me. But i should get more than one result.