# How to retrieve the SP list items without using CAML Query?

Tags: javascript, caml-query, jsom

I have a SharePoint list and I need to get all items from that list without using CAML Query in JSOM.

How can I do this?

Comment: If you really want to avoid using CAML, check [this old post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/130409/how-to-create-a-search-using-sharepoint-jsom) on using Search from JSOM.  But honestly, calling getItems on the list with a nearly empty CAML is far easier: `<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' /></OrderBy></Query>`

Comment: Also you can use REST calls to retrieve data

Answer (score 1):

Try using your code something like below:

```
var oListItems;

function GetAllListItems() {
    // You can optionally specify the Site URL here to get the context
    // If you don't specify the URL, the method will get the context of the current site
    // var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext("http://MyServer/sites/SiteCollection");
    clientContext = new SP.ClientContext();

    var oWeb = clientContext.get_web();

    // Specify list title here
    var oList = oWeb.get_lists().getByTitle("List Name");

    // Get all list items from the list
    // This method will get all the items from all the folders and sub folders including folders and sub folders too
    oListItems = oList.getItems(SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery());

    // Load list items to Client Context
    clientContext.load(oListItems);

    // Execute the query to the server.
    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onsuccess, onfailed);
}

function onsuccess() {

    // Iterate through Enumerator
    var oEnumerator = oListItems.getEnumerator();

    while (oEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        // get_item("ColumnName")
        var oListItem = oEnumerator.get_current().get_item('Title');
        console.log("Name : " + oListItem);
    }
}

function onfailed(sender, args) {
    console.log('Failed' + args.get_message() + '\n' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

**Reference**: [Get All Items in SharePoint using JSOM](http://www.codesharepoint.com/jsom/get-all-items-in-sharepoint-using-jsom).